# Can't see blender bake tab

Tags: rendering

Under render properties I can't see the bake tab. I've tried loading factory settings and OptiX is not enabled in preferences, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you are in Eevee? In that case, switch to Cycles

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bake in Eevee, you need to switch from Eevee to Cycles.